# Create a schema with the name passed by variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create a schema with with a name passed by variable.
Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1("name" character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
'CREATE SCHEMA "name";'
  LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use plpgsql and than EXECUTE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1("name" character varying)
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA '|| quote_ident($1); -- security

    RETURN;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE
COST 20;
```

Comment: Recommend you make the function idempotent by using `.. IF NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 3):

user search_path to change the default schema so you may easily add tables to it!
and use format with %I to escape the schema name as identifier.

like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1("name" character varying)
RETURNS void AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('CREATE SCHEMA %I;', $1);
    EXECUTE FORMAT('SET search_path TO %I;', $1);

    CREATE TABLE table1(
    column1 integer
    );

    RETURN;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE
COST 20;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [PROCEDURE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) (PostgreSQL 11+)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_schema( _schema text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql as
$$
  BEGIN
        EXECUTE format( 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS %I ',_schema); 
  END
$$;
```

Call this procedure via:

```
call create_schema('test');
```